# Angularfire2 *ngfor not updating DOM in Ionic 2 app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2, ngfor

I'm making a social media app using Ionic with a Firebase backend that I communicate with using Angularfire2.

There's a page in my app that lists all the followers of a user by receiving a uid from the NavParams and sends this to a provider that returns a FirebaseListObservable with that user's followers.

**followers-page.ts**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public util: UtilProvider,  public userProvider: UserProvider, public socialProvider: SocialProvider, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.name = this.navParams.get('name');
    this.otherUid = this.navParams.get('uid');
    this.currentUid = this.userProvider.currentUid();
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.users = this.userProvider.getUserFollowers(this.otherUid);
    });
}
```

**followers-page.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color='danger'>
        <ion-title>{{name}} Followers</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item style="background-color: #fff" *ngIf="!(users | async)">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <img src="assets/img/defaultAvatar.png">
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </ion-avatar>
        </ion-item>

        <user-item *ngFor="let user of users | async" [user]="user">
        </user-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**user-provider.ts**

```
//Get List of followers of uid
getUserFollowers(uid) {
    let users = this.af.database.list(`/users/${uid}/followers`, {
        query: {
            limitToFirst: 10
        }
    });
    return users;
}
```

**user-item.html**

```
<ion-item style="background-color: #fff" text-wrap>
    <ion-avatar item-left (click)="userProfile()">
        <img [class]="user.visibility > 1 ? 'profile-pic verified' : 'profile-pic'" [src]="user?.avatar ? user.avatar : 'assets/img/defaultAvatar.png'">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2 (click)="userProfile(user)">{{user?.name}}</h2>
    <button ion-button item-right *ngIf="!(following)" (click)="followUser()">{{user?.followerCount}} Followers</button>
    <button ion-button outline item-right icon-left *ngIf="following" (click)="followUser()">
        <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>Followed
    </button>
</ion-item>
```

Without the limitToFirst query it displays the correct number of followers as user-items but the profile avatar and the name and the follower status are all blank.  When I click on the avatar it pushes the correct user-profile page so the data is there but the DOM isn't being updated.

[image: image0]

I have this exact same code in the discover tab of my app (without the NgZone) and it works perfectly there.

[image: image1]

I tried it without the NgZone here as well but to no avail so I am just about completely lost as to how to get these users' info to display.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is not triggered in the `user-item` component

Comment: @Aravind is there a way to ensure it gets triggered?

Comment: update the post with modified code

Comment: Try put the code in `IonViewWillEnter()`. I get the feeling that the view loads but the call to firebase is still in progress after the view loads and so displays blank.  By the time you click the data has loaded and then navigates fine. Best practice is to have a loader showing while the fetch to the server is in progress

Comment: tried both suggestions but none of these seem to work :/